# Hiding parts of a GameObject in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here's my setup:

[image]

There are two game objects on the scene. One is the Top Content and the other is the Scrollable Area. Each contain other game objects inside them. I've shown the areas with yellow color for telling the problem but actually they don't have any backgrounds (sprites). The scene has a single sprite for the background that covers all the scene.

The bottom area is scrollable in every way with swipe gestures.

My problem is, when the user scrolls the bottom area to top, I want it's contents to become invisible when they reach the borders of the Top Content area. When I scroll the bottom area, it's contents slide under the top contents, resulting in a very ugly appearance.

Is there a way to accomplish this without using any of the UI controls?

Comment: Thanks @derHugo but did you actually read my last sentence?

Comment: Nope ^^ sorry my bad, but so you basically want a Mask but for non Canvas content?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: If you don't want to use UI controls you'll probably have to write a stencil shader for it (if i'm understanding your question correctly) https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html where the comparison function passes when its inside your scrolling area and fails otherwise